# wordpress: want to show only admin posts on home page

Tags: wordpress

Suppose i have a blog where lots of people post their post under different category. But i want to show only those post on home page which are posted by a admin. Rest of the author post will be shown under specific users pages.

So is there any plugins available for this? or any code that might help me to fullfil my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$query = new WP_Query( 'author=1' );

userid 1 is always admin, if you havent changed it, if you have multiple admins please have it : $query = new WP_Query( 'author=2,6,17,38' );

You can read more about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Good luck!
Marten